# ATI 6470m & intel HD graphics 3000 drivers?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, dell

I have a Dell 15R 2nd Gen with an ATI 6470m GPU and Intel HD graphics 3000 (form the i5 processor). I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 and can't get the graphics card to install. In system information it comes up as unknown. I've heard that there currently isn't any way to switch between ATI & Intel graphics processors on Ubuntu, I don't know how true that is. I just want the graphics card working properly. I've been searching a while now but no luck. Any help and information will be most appreciated.

Comment: I've also read about the ATI 6470m overheating, not really seeing any signs of that at the moment

Answer (score 2):

I have an intel core i3 with hybrid graphics too (ati+intel) and the only solution that i found was to disable the intel card on bios to use the ATI on ubuntu. Then i installed the ATI driver selecting restricted drivers. Currently, hybrid graphics isn't well supported on linux so, maybe its better we wait a few more months.

Edit: If you want, you can read the comunity documents about hybrid graphics and how to change both graphics but as i said, its better to wait a few more months for more support.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this page for the most up-to-date info on the issue:

http://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux