# how to install swichable radoen hd 6470M drivers for ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, ati, vga, vgaswitcheroo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ATI 6470m & intel HD graphics 3000 drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95459/ati-6470m-intel-hd-graphics-3000-drivers)

i have hp pavilion g6 i5 laptop with Radoen hd 6470M switchable VGA. i installed it the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS but VGA drivers doesn't work properly. 
i want to install drivers into the Ubuntu. but when i do it arrived error massage like this

"sorry, installation of this driver failed. Please have a look at the log file for details:/var/log/jockey.log"

i dont know what can i do now! help me.

~$ lspci -nn | grep VGA

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M Series] [1002:6760]
```

Comment: ~$ lspci -nn | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M Series] [1002:6760]

Comment: As noted in the other question, there are ways to get it working.  You should watch the Hybrid graphics project page for details

Answer (score 0):

These instructions have worked well for me:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450